# How do I operate on multiple layers at once in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers, crop

I have a image file which has a large number of card images, each in its own layer. I would like to crop these images to the proper size with rounded-rectangle corners. (I got the images as formatted for printing, with extra bleed.) I can easily crop the entire image to a rectangle, and I can make a selection that has just the triangular corner regions. But how do I clear all the triangular corners simultaneously in GIMP, without going through each layer individually? Do I need to write a script to do this?

I am using GIMP 2.8.20 on Debian GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script already exists: [clear-layers](http://gimp-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml).

If you have one single image, you can also do it directly in the Python console (Filters>Python-fu>Console):

```
image=gimp.image_list()[0]
for layer in image.layers:
    pdb.gimp_edit_clear(layer)
```